# Сколько строк кода можно писать внутри условия if в js?

Tags: javascript

я новичок, и как я понял в количестве строк нет ограничений, я прав?

Comment: да, ты прав. а в связи с чем возник вопрос?

Comment: Формально ограничение только одно - накопитель, на котором лежит файл скрипта, не резиновый. Да и на размер самого файла есть ограничения.

Comment: @Akina  также есть ограничение накладываемое свободным RAM для загрузки скрипта

Comment: @DiD это можно обойти добавлением файла подкачки требуемого размера

Comment: Зависит от того, что значит «можно». Технически можно — это да, но если строки перестают влезать экран, стоит задуматься о выделении этих строк в отдельную функцию или метод.

Answer (score 2):

Особых ограничений нет, главное ограничить код фигурными скобками:

```js
if (otvet == 2015) {
  alert("Правильно!");
  alert("Вы такой умный!");
} else {
  alert("Ошибка!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Внутри блока `{}` пишите сколько хотите строк, без этого только 1 строку можно

вариант 1:

```
if (a == b) {
    // строка 1
    // строка 2

    // строка N
}
else
    // строка 1
```

вариант 2:

```
if (a == b)
    // строка 1
else
    // строка 1
```

вариант 3

```
if (a == b) {
    // строка 1
    // строка 2

    // строка N
}
else {
    // строка 1
    // строка 2

    // строка N
}
```